# How to press Keyboard keys using PHP in Behat?

Tags: php, behat, mink

I'm using Behat with Mink functions and some custom functions to automate some websites. I hit a bump where I need to click 2 options from a list. Manually I need to press the "Control" button to select the second option. I'm trying to find help here to do the same with the automation tool.
All our other functions in the Mink library were developed in PHP, hence I need some code in php.

Comment: Welcome SO, Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then modify your question. So that we can help.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? According to the title, you want to press some keys, while you are refering to selection of options in your text. Additionally, what have you tried so far? Have you tried looking up your use case in the documentation?

Comment: Lets say I have a list of items 1 through 10
When I manually want to select 2 options out of 10, I select Option4 then I press the Ctrl key and select Option 6

How can I press ctrl button using php

Comment: I found this one:
code:
    /**
     * Presses specific keyboard key.
     *
     * param mixed  $char     could be either char ('b') or char-code (98)
     * param string $modifier keyboard modifier (could be 'ctrl', 'alt', 'shift' or 'meta')
     */
    public function keyPress($char, $modifier = null)
    {
        $this->getSession()->getDriver()->keyPress($this->getXpath(), $char, $modifier);
    }

Not sure how to pass "ctrl" into the statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misconception here. When using Behat plus Mink you don't have to emulate pressing a key to select multiple options from an options list. Mink's `selectOption()` method has a bool parameter `multiple` - set it to true when selecting the second option. See the documentation / [source](https://github.com/minkphp/Mink/blob/master/src/Element/NodeElement.php) of class `NodeElement` for details.